# Neural networking diverging on the same item in all tests

Tags: optimization, neural-network

I am having problem finding a cause for diverging values in all tests of my multilayer neural network for recognizing hand written patterns.

Here is a photo of output:

[image]

Each column represents a specific letter. The result should be that first letter would dominate in first row, second letter in second row, ...

In every run of few tests, one letter dominates in all values. What could be a cause for this?

Comment: What kind of neural networks you use? Do you use some particular NN framework?

Answer (score 0):

Answer can depend to some degree from kind of neural network model that you use ( 
Perceptron, backprop, recurrent neural network, LSTM ) but what is easy to notice is data that you feed into your NN. Three inputs that you mentioned are very close to each other. First column has very small difference between each other. They are quite identical: 0.31659 and 0.31660. Second column has the same challenge for NN:0.3993. And third column is also quite similar: 0.2657. For NN it's not easy to build some kind of manifold that separated between those values. You should consider somehow to increase contrast between those three columns because they look pretty similar to each other. NN considers those changes as insignificant and you need many iterations before you'll be able to build hyperplane which correctly classifies your letters.

Comment: Hey, @user115 did you find my answer useful ?